# How to execute C++ code when java button is clicked?

Tags: java, c++

I'm working on a java GUI button that when I click on it a C++ file has to run. I've tried 'filename = new filename' but that doesn't seem to work.

I'm working on the latest version of Eclipse in a Windows environment.

```
JButton button = new JButton("Done");
      button.addActionListener(
         new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
         });
```

Comment: Isn't there a way instead of hard coding the C++ code to just call the file for that functionality?

Comment: whatever the functionality you want to implement you can have inside actionPerformed() method. Please post your code of what you want to implement here to get more insights

Comment: @JeffHardy _"a C++ file has to run"_ C++ source code cannot be simply _"run"_, you have to compile it, and if you're lucky it will output as an executable file, that you can invoke from your java code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ProcessBuilder` class for this purpose. Wokring Code:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Done");
    button.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder();
                try
                {
                    process.command("g++", "Program.cpp", "-o", "Program");
                    process.start().waitFor();  // will wait till the compilation
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());  // print any exception if thrown
                }
            }
         });
```

Comment: This compiles the Program.cpp code.  You would presumably need to also make sure the code compiles, and then run it.   I'm pretty sure this isn't what the OP needs.

Comment: What do you want to say ? Should I check for errors then correct them then compile the code and then run it ?.. Hahaa... I can't be achieved pragmatically. I think the code will be error-free in the first place.

Comment: @ZainArshad I tried your code, it does compile the code but doesn't run it. It creates a .exe file of the C++ file I'm trying to run. When I run the .exe file it does run the C++ code, but what it really needs to do is when I click the button "Done", it should compile and automatically run the C++ file I have.

Comment: see if it runs via `cmd` if you explicitly tries to run it ? meanwhile let me update my answer

Comment: The .exe file does runs in CDM and it does what it supposed to do.

Comment: ok wait a while i am updating the answer it will run the .exe file as well

Comment: process.command("g++", "-o", "Program.exe", "Program.cpp");
 process.start()

Comment: add this to in above code after first process.start()...... you got what you want ?

Comment: process.command("g++.exe", "ared.cpp", "-o", "ared");
process.start().waitFor(); // will wait till the compilation
process.command("g++", "-o", "ared.exe", "ared.cpp"); process.start();

Comment: You mean to add it like that?

Comment: yes ... see if it works ? actually i am not on laptop so i cant run and test it myself thats why i am asking you.. pardon me

Comment: It still do the same nothing has changed.

Comment: process.command("g++", "ared.cpp", "-o", "ared.exe"); process.start().waitFor();

Comment: use only this ... remove all other commands in the `try` block